# Given a 1st-order $\phi$ in the language of $\{\in,c\}$, is $\langle M,\in, S\rangle\models\phi$ 1st-order expressible?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I've proven that, given a first-order $\phi$ in the language $\in$ and $v\in M^{<\omega}$, there is a first-order formula $\psi(M,v)$ that is equivalent to $\langle M,\in\rangle\models\phi(v)$. Specifically, this formula is simply $\phi(v)$ with all quantification over $M$. Although the paper is still being written, you may see the proof in the paper which I am writing [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59e811659fef423e0028b5a9).

This brings up an interesting conjecture, which is the following:

*Given a first-order sentence $\phi$ in the language $\{\in,c\}$ where $c$ is a constant symbol and some class $M$, $\langle M,\in,S\rangle\models\phi$ is equivalent to $M\models\psi(S)$ for some first-order $\psi$.*

What is the proof of this conjecture? It seems intuitively true if one lets $\psi$ to be $\phi$ with $c$ replaced by the parameter of $\psi$.

Comment: Just FYI: the observation in your first paragraph is completely standard and is covered in any textbook that talks about models of set theory. The formula $\psi$ is called the "relativization of $\phi$ to $M$"

Comment: Sorry. The textbook I have isn't really about models of set theory; rather models of group theory, graph theory, etc. The main set theory in the book is simply cardinals used for naming models $\kappa$-Categorical or $\kappa$-Stable.

Comment: What textbook do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just let $\psi$ be $\phi$ with every instance of the symbol $c$ replaced by some variable which does not occur in $\phi$.  You can prove this by induction on formulas.  More precisely, suppose $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a formula with free variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and let $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$ be the formula obtained by replacing all instances of $c$ with a new variable $y$.  Then by induction on $\phi$, you prove that for any $v_1,\dots,v_n\in M$, $\langle M,\in,S\rangle\vDash \phi(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is equivalent to $\langle M,\in\rangle \vDash \psi(v_1,\dots,v_n,S)$.

Comment: I realized that quite early on, but I couldn't figure out how to prove it; induction on formulas led nowhere for me, and I couldn't really figure out how to prove it any other way. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: What difficulty do you have with induction on formulas?  It seems completely straightforward to me...

Comment: Well, I can prove that it holds for all quantifier-free sentences. However, it gets difficult once I have to prove that it holds for $\forall x(\phi(x))$. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to prove it not just for sentences but for formulas.  That is, prove by induction on formulas $\phi$ that $\phi(v)$ is equivalent to $\psi(v,S)$ for any assignment $v$ of elements of $M$ to the free variables of $\phi$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm terribly sorry for not noticing that earlier. Thank you very much.